# modal update has delay to set new State in react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, bootstrap-modal, setstate

I have some problem with updating the editModal (react bootstrap modal).
after dispatching the action it works and I'm able to fetch single pet data as an object.
[and redux dev tools confirms that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLzVI.jpg) 
But modal doesn't open at first attempt and I need to click the (edit button: doesn't matter which one) again to show filled input data ,and each time I click the edit button for first pet or second pet it doesn't update modal and it shows data related to the previously clicked edit
[and as you see I clicked the second edit and data has fetched as redux dev tools shows correctly but Modal still shows first pet details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UHIf.jpg)

thanks for your help :)

here's my code

```
const PetScreen = () => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch()

    //part of state that comes from store.js
    const petDetailByUser = useSelector((state) => state.petDetailByUser)


//when action dispatch petDetails fills with single pet Details ex:_id,editPetName,...
    const { petDetailLoading, petDetails } = petDetailByUser
       

    const [editPetName, setEditPetName] = useState('')

    //edit button dispatch getPetDetail and get pet data as an object
     const editButtonHandler = (id) => {
        dispatch(getPetDetails(id))
        if (petDetails) {
          setEditPetName(petDetails.editPetName)
    //shows edit modal
         handleEditShow()
        }
      }
      
      
     //this field is inside react modal body 
     <Form.Control
          type='text'
          placeholder='Pet Name'
          name='editPetName'
          value={editPetName}
          onChange={(e) => setEditPetName(e.target.value)}
           >
    </Form.Control>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just after `dispatch(getPetDetails(id))`, the `editPetName` variable has not been refreshed yet so it contains the name of the previous pet.

You can fix it by using an effect to update `editPetName` when `petDetails` is updated.

```
const petDetailByUser = useSelector((state) => state.petDetailByUser)
const { petDetailLoading, petDetails } = petDetailByUser;

const [editPetName, setEditPetName] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  if (petDetails) {
    setEditPetName(petDetails.editPetName);
    handleEditShow();
  }
}, [petDetails]);

const editButtonHandler = (id) => dispatch(getPetDetails(id));
```

Comment: it works......thank you so dear Olivier :) .....God bless you